# Trying to find where I went wrong in my python code

Tags: python, 3d

I am trying to do two things. I want a set of data to print out in 3d with z, theta, and r as my axes, and I want to have it calculate using the equations I gave it. I don't understand why this is not working when I give it this code.

```
from math import *
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D



G=6.6738480e-11
c=2.99792458e8
Msun=1.9891e30
M=4*(Msun)
r=linspace((3*(M/Msun)*1000),(8*(M/Msun)*1000),1000)
a=.98

theta=arange(0,2*pi,pi/100)
rho=(sqrt((r**2)+((a**2)*(cos**2(theta)))))
delta=((r**2)+(a**2)-(2*M*r))
sigma=(sqrt((((r**2)+(a**2))**2)-((a**2)*delta*(sin**2(theta)))))

z=((1/(sigma(rho(sqrt(delta)))))-1)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
p = ax.plot_surface(r, theta, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
cb = fig.colorbar(p, shrink=0.5)
show()
```

I am pretty sure I am using the 3d axes thing wrong, beyond that though I get this error:

```
---> 52 rho=(sqrt((r**2)+((a**2)*(cos**2(theta)))))
     53 delta=((r**2)+(a**2)-(2*M*r))
     54 sigma=(sqrt((((r**2)+(a**2))**2)-((a**2)*delta*(sin**2(theta)))))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Am I entering this incorrectly? Should I use a different syntax?
Any help is appreciated. What I want to do is calculate z, as this will give me my redshift, and I want to plot it with increasing r and theta. I seem to be doing something wrong.

Comment: `2(theta)` is not possible.

Comment: neither cos**2(something)

Answer (score 2):

In line 52, `cos**2(theta)` is bad syntax; should be `cos(theta)**2`

Similarly, in line 54, `sin**2(theta)` should be `sin(theta)**2`.

Comment: Thanks. That was simple! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

KO: mistake is here

```
rho=(sqrt((r**2)+((a**2)*(cos**2(theta)))))
```

rigth way to sqrt cos is

```
rho=(sqrt((r**2)+((a**2)*(cos2(theta)**2))))
```